# regex with ? and { } quantifiers

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to validate numbers that checks the year for leap year. here's a part of the code. for some reason this code would let number 4 8 24 28 as a valid regex.

```
(0{2}?)
([2468][480] | [13579][26])



pattern = re.compile (r"""

    ((0{2}?)([2468][480] | [13579][26]))

    """, re.X)
```

when I left out

```
(0{2}?)
```

24 12 and everything works..

I'm using verbose so spacing shouldn't matter..

Invalid

```
12
24
28
16
```

EDIT :: Actually all is invalid now..

i don't understand why 24 is invalid and 28 is invalid this doesn't make sense at all. I appreciate your guidance.

Comment: But why use regex for validating leap year.

Comment: Why would you ever use `{1}`? It does nothing.

Comment: We have a problem.  "Wait, I know regex."  Now we have two problems.

Comment: Wait, you just changed the regex. What are we supposed to be debugging here? Don't give us a moving target.

Comment: lol.. it's just an assignment. we learned regex and the professor is testing out our understanding of regex.

Comment: oh sorry i just changed the regex but i reduced it to where the problem is

Comment: Can you show us runnable code that demonstrates the problem, with actual syntax and actual spacing?

Comment: The spaces are being interpreted. That's why `24` and `28` are invalid

Comment: Spaces in verbose mode doesn't count..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `(0{2}?)`, that means “match two `0`s here, but match as few as possible”. Non-greediness doesn’t really make sense for an `{n}` quantifier (it does for `{n,}`, and `{m,n}`) – did you mean `(0{2})?`?

Oh, and do keep in mind that years divisible by 400 *are* leap years.

Comment: Yes that's my mistake. Thank you! What kind of mistake what am I looking for and which documentation should I look at? Thanks so much.

Comment: @LeonardLie: I don’t think this is specifically documented anywhere, but most quantifiers can have a `?` appended to them to make them non-greedy. Just remember that a quantifier can’t directly follow a quantifier.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `re.DEBUG` flag to show debug info about the expression, we get

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'0{2}?', re.DEBUG)
min_repeat 2 2
  literal 48
```

The `min_repeat` shows that `0{2}?` isn't being interpreted as `?` applied to `0{2}`. It's being interpreted as a lazy quantifier, attempting to match 0 any number of times from 2 to 2, but as few as possible. This doesn't quite seem consistent with the documentation; the docs only show the `{m,n}?` form.